# Is it possible to check if a PDF is CMYK or RGB using GhostScript?

Tags: ghostscript

Is it possible to check if a PDF is CMYK or RGB using GhostScript?

I am aware of the inkcov feature, but this just returns values in terms of CMYK (with silent conversion)?

Is the real check, a check for RGB colours or RGB images within the PDF? not sure if both RGB and CMYK images can exist in the same PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images aren't the only thing that can be in a PDF file, you can also have text, linework and shadings. Also transparency blending can be specified in specific colour spaces. Colour spaces are not limited to RGB or CMYK but can also include Gray and spot (Separation) colours, as well as ICCBased colour spaces and certain specific CIE colour spaces such as Lab.

All of these colour spaces can potentially be present in a PDF file simultaneously.

Ghostscript doesn't contain any tools currently to tell you what colour spaces are used in a PDF file, though the pdf_info.ps script could be modified to do so for unusual (not grey/RGB/CMYK) spaces. You could also write a small piece of PostScript which could tell you when a colour space was used, and what kind of colour it is.

The inkcov device is a CMYK device, so all colours specified in the PDF are converted to CMYK before being 'printed' to the inkcov device which counts up the coverage. It doesn't tell you anything about the original PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a PDF can contain both RGB and CMYK images, so you'd need to have a tool that can review all images and report on their mode.

If GhostScript doesn't include options to do so, you may have to write a script to use a PDF library for parsing the image and reporting details on the elements it contains.

For example, this [Cam::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.58/lib/CAM/PDF.pm) module in Perl says it can parse any PDF v1.5 formatted file.